# Shell script unable to read output from Azure CLI command correctly

Tags: bash, azure, shell, azure-cli

I am trying to run an Azure CLI command inside a shell script and unable to resolve the below issue.

Operation I am trying to do : Delete all resource groups starting with 'test' within a subscription. In this regard when I execute the below commands for deleting the resource group individually outside of the script, it works fine :

```
az login
rg='test.example1'
az group delete -g $rg --subscription <sub-id> -y
```

However, when I try to do the below inside the shall script, I am getting a validation error : **ValidationError: Parameter 'g' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'.**

This is my shell script snippet :

```
for rg in $(az group list --subscription <sub-id> --query [].name); do
   if [[ "$rg" =~ test* ]];then
      echo "Deleting resource group : $rg"
      az group delete -g $rg --subscription <sub-id> -y
   fi
done
```

The echo is showing the resource group as expected within quotes, like

```
Deleting resource group :"test.example1"
```

I have a hunch that the $rg in the az group delete command is not being read correctly. However, I am unable to figure out how I can fix that.

Update : Added the screenshot @[CharlesXu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9773937/charles-xu). Please note I added the break to limit the deletion to just one resource group during testing.
[image]

Comment: The line `rg = 'test.example1'` does not assign a value to `rg`.  I would suspect you get an error message from that line.

Comment: Updated. It was a typo with the space around =. Removed that from the snippet above

Comment: Side problem: the test in `if [[ "$rg" =~ test* ]]` probably isn't doing what you want -- it'll match if the value contains "tes" anywhere. This is because `=~` does regular expression matching, and the regex `test*` matches "tes" followed by zero or more "t" characters (and the match isn't anchored, so it'll match anywhere in the string). You probably want a glob pattern match instead; to get that, use `=` instead of `=~`.

Comment: I guess thats not a problem because the echo inside the if block is printing what I expect it to print . I mentioned that in the OP as well. `echo "Deleting resource group : $rg"`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is all about quotes.  If echo is printing the line:

`Deleting resource group :"test.example1"`

that indicates that the variable rg has double quotes in it.  When you call:

`az group delete -g $rg --subscription <sub-id> -y`

it is the same as if you called:

`az group delete -g '"test.example1"' --subscription <sub-id> -y`

which is almost certainly not what you want.  You need to get the quotes out of the variable.  A simple (but arguably terrible) approach is to use `eval`.  A better approach would be to modify the call to `az` so that it does not emit the quotes.  Another approach would be to use a bash extension and write:

`az group delete -g "${rg//\"/}" --subscription <sub-id> -y`

Comment: Thanks! But using the above command is still throwing the same error.

Comment: @user5566364 Try putting `set -x` before the relevant section, so you can see what the shell thinks is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output you have seen should like this:

```
Deleting resource group :"test.example1",
```

And I can reproduce it:

[image]

The problem is that the element of the list for group names come with `,`. So you need to command that get the list of group names into this:

```
az group list --subscription <sub-id> --query [].name -o tsv
```

And then it works fine and like this:

[image]

I do not want to delete the groups, so I change the command to show them as examples.

Update:

To filter the group with the test prefix, you can do it when you get the group names in the list:

```
az group list --subscription <sub-id> --query [].name -o tsv | grep '^test'
```

Then you do not need the `if` condition.

Comment: Tried this, but no luck.

Comment: @user5566364 The same error? Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: Added the screenshot. Please note - I have intentionally added the break statement to limit the damage( if any) during testing.

Comment: @user5566364 The same error as I reproduce. And I cannot see the whole group name you display. Can you share the screenshot without hiding the name after "Deleting resource group :"?

Comment: Updated with the requested screenshot

Comment: @user5566364 It's wired, all things work fine on my side. Do you run the script in Linux?

Comment: Windows, using git bash though.

Comment: @user5566364 I recommend you use the WSL in Windows. Then it will work.

Comment: @user5566364 Any updates on this question? Do you mind using the WSL?